# php loading image failed cause of dimension

Tags: php, image, load

i'm trying to load on a site an image, but this code works only with image less then 100k, when i try to load a 256k or less image this check fails

```
$formato=array("jpg","gif","png");

$info = pathinfo( $_FILES["img_c"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

if ( ( $_FILES["img_c"]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES["img_c"]["type"] =="image/gif" || $_FILES["img_c"]["type"] == "image/png"  )& $_FILES["img_c"]["size"] < 256000 && in_array( $info, $formato ) )
```

Comment: I would check the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` hidden input field. (There's a form before this code, right?)

Comment: fails **HOW**? out of memory? file not found?

Comment: @Ofir y there is a form, where is the MAX_FILE_SIZE?